# input the integer N and return the matrix A as output and print it on console

Tags: c

I want to have that below one. it is like increase the input prom the user by one for each column.

```
12345
23456
34567
45678
56789
```

But what I have is

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

Can you help me?

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)    
{  
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)  
    {  
        mat[i][j]= start++;
        printf("%d ",mat[i][j]);  
    }  
    printf("\n");  
  }  
}
```

Comment: C++ or C?  Those are different languages, and will have different answers.

Comment: Where exactly do you have those numbers? Can you include variable declarations + initialization too?

Comment: I need to do it in c

Comment: @SabuhaRajanKaya We do not understand your question, can you provide [mcve]

Comment: Do you want the output, the matrix, or both?

Comment: @Lundin it didnt let me to write all the code, it says it is mostly done from code.editor issue. But I can share on comment.

Comment: I want the matrix, outpput is  a matrix.

Comment: Change `mat[i][j]= start++;` to `mat[i][j]= i + j + 1;`.

Comment: @isrnick this is perfect, it is working, but how?

Comment: Do I guess correctly that you want to output the sum of a number from input, row index and column index? That seems to match your description and shown desired output. (same as isrnick comment I just realise....)

Comment: Sorry to say, but that "how?" is exactly why you have this assignment. The idea is that it helps you figure out this kind of relationships of numbers. I recommend to use a debugger to step through the code which does what you want and follow its activities in detail. If that does not help, maybe doing the preceding assignments again, and on your own, helps.

Comment: @SabuhaRajanKaya Sure it does, simply edit the post and include the declaration/initialization.

Comment: @Lundin No, for users with low rep, that does not work. They have a certain ratio of code to prose enforced in their posts.... I am sure you knew that, even if it is some time that it applied to you.... ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch What are you talking about bro?! I couldnt edit, because I am new. It gave error, and didnt let me post the way that I want. You cant judge somone like that. That is really rude.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm aware of no such limit. Anyway, without the declaration it isn't really possible to answer.

Comment: Sabuha, sorry for the misunderstanding, but you confirm precisely what I said. The system prevents you from posting more code. It requirs you to include a certain amount of explanation in non-code text. There is not a trace of an attack in your diection in what I wrote. I was reminding Lundin of that mechansim which did not allow you to post more code, exactly as you described. Lundin has already confirmed that they are not aware of that mechanism. From my point of view I was actually defending your position. However, I apologise even for giving you an unpleasant impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset start after each run:

```c
mat[N][N]= mat[temp-start][start+N];



for(i=0;i<N;i++)    
{  
    start = i+input;      /// here  
/* If what I understand from the question is correct,
 * this will solve another problem because the top left
 * corner of the matrix will be the value of [input] */ 
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)  

    {  
    mat[i][j]= start++;
      printf("%d ",mat[i][j]);  

    }  
    printf("\n");  



  }
```

[Full program (doesn't take input)](https://rentry.co/gs4st) , [run](http://cpp.sh/6umwa)

Comment: @sabuha does this answer your question, because it does produce the right result?